# Ponticello notation in Guitar Pro 6

Tags: notation, classical-guitar, guitar-pro

Is it possible to add a ponticello (near the bridge, bright sound) notation in Guitarpro 6 for Classical Guitar compositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the text *sul ponticello* next to whatever place in the score that you want it to be seen.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Williams, would it be possible to get a ponticello effect when playing back the track in GuitarPro as well?